# Swap parts of a list in python

Tags: python, list, inline, swap

Suppose I have,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to swap the list splice a[:2] with a[-2:]. So that a becomes [4,5,3,1,2]

Is there a pythonic way to do this?

EDIT1: After the first answer, I tried this,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[:2],a[-2:]=a[-2:][:2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
```

There was an exception, whcih I got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using slice assignment with tuple unpacking:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[:2], a[-2:] = a[-2:], a[:2]
>>> a
[4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: also, whilst I agree with @falsetru that this is the pythonic way to assign slices, Python encourages you to be as easily readable as possible. Unless things are getting ugly memory-wise or are performance critical, maybe actually going for a temporary variable *might* be clearer, depending on how complex your swapping problem becomes. In this case, this solution is the easiest to read, though, I think.

Comment: @MarcusMuller What is your suggestion then?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, For me, introducing a temporary variable make it unreadable.

Comment: My first intuition was this, but somehow my python interpreter gives an error, `TypeError: can only assign an iterable`. Any idea?

Comment: @VineetMenon, Could you show the statement you tried, and the full traceback?

Comment: Well, as said, in this case, a temporary variable would be harder to read; However, assuming the case get's more complex, and you'd want to swap a dozen slices, then making a list of these slices and then using a list comprehension *might* be easier. Really, I feel it depends on how complex your swapping becomes (and how complex the rules for deciding what to swap are).

Comment: @falsetru, edited the qustion to add exception trace.

Comment: @VineetMenon, You missed a colon on the right side of the assignment: `>>> a[:2], a[-2:] = a[-2:][:2]` should be `>>> a[:2], a[-2:] = a[-2:], [:2]`

Comment: @MarcusMuller Show an example. How can you even use a temporary variable here??? It makes it look even less readable. Please how us

Comment: `>>> r = range(100)`  
`>>> slices = [slice(*v) for v in [(1,10), (91,100), (61,80,2)]`    just to have the slices come out of somewhere, be of variable number, length and stride  
`>>> [r[slice(*v)] for v in [(91,100), (61,80,2), (1,10)] = [r[slice] for slice in slices]`  
File "<input>", line 1  
SyntaxError: can't assign to list comprehension  
  

  
As you can see, if you programatically need to assign slices, you will either need an explicit loop iterating over the slices to be re-assigned, or you will need a helper variable holding your values until you can assign them.